# Ring homomorphism and units homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that given $\phi: R\rightarrow R'$ is a ring homomorphism $R, R'$ are rings, there exist a homomorphism between the group of units that is $\phi': R^\times\rightarrow R'^\times$ is a group homomorphism.
I was able to  show that the the ring homomorphism maps units to units but I am not sure how to check the homomorphism condition explicitly.

Comment: I am sorry.. what is your question?

Comment: The homomorphism condition for $\phi'$ is that $\phi'(xy) = \phi'(x)\phi'(y)$ for all units $x,y \in R^\times$, correct? You seem to be using the map $\phi$ restricted to $R^\times$ for your $\phi'$, so what do we know about the multiplicative properties of $\phi$?

Comment: @Alqatrkapa: We know that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ so this condition will also hold for our restricted map?

Comment: @RutherfordMark Precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you're using $\phi'=\phi\rvert_{R^\times}$, that is, the restriction of $\phi$ to $R^\times$.)

Then, the statement follows trivially from the fact that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism: From
$$\forall x,y\in R.\quad \phi(x\cdot y)=\phi(x)\cdot\phi(y) $$
and $R^\times\subseteq R$, it is obvious that
$$\forall x,y\in R^\times.\quad \phi'(x\cdot y)=\phi'(x)\cdot\phi'(y) \text.$$